# WCF to Android communication and vice versa

Tags: c#, android, wcf, soa, wshttpbinding

Hi guys I would like to ask how to talk with my WCF service using Android Java im using wsHttpBinding in my WCF and I would like my android to send and receive service by calling methods exposed by my WCF. also how to deal with data contracts in android because im using add service reference in visual studio. could you guys please help? thanks...

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669764/how-to-consume-wcf-service-with-android

Comment: Here's a link to a question as I was having an issue when I was working on this a couple of weeks go. Hopefully my question will contain all the info and code you would need to get you started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819761/consuming-wcf-soap-service-running-on-mono-from-android-ksoap2

Comment: Is it also possible use transactions in android if your wcf service operation requires transaction(mandatory)?